# Row Level Permission on multiple tables in Db2

Tags: row-level-security, db2-10.5, db2-zos

If there are 3 tables that have foreign key relationship and I am giving row level permission on 1 table does that permission also apply to the other 2 tables automatically?  Or do I need to give row level permission on all the 3 tables separately  .

for eg
Table 1
Asia India
Newyork US

Table 2
nagpur india orange
NJ      US   liberty

table3
xxxx  nagpur yyyy
zzzz  NJ     ffff

now if I give row level permission asia user, does it implies on table 2,3

Answer (score 0):

> If there is 3 tables and having foreign key relationship and I am giving row level permission on 1 table does it applicable to all the other 2 tables automatically Or I need to give row level permission on all the 3 tables seprately .

You need to explicitly add Row-Level Security to each table you want locked down. It doesn't matter that they have a foreign key relationship.

Comment: Thank you !! is there any way around to solve this apart from explicitly putting lock on each table

Comment: @singlas Not really, no. Just regular [authorization](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=security-db2-model#c0021804__title__3) can be used to secure objects themselves. You'd still have to be explicit though, and this controls who can access whole objects, so there's no granularity to allow access to only parts of the data within those objects - that's the purpose of Row-Level Security.